# How to check logical and physical file size on disk using C# file API

Tags: c#

How to read the logical and physical file size using C# api.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750590/c-get-file-size-on-disk

Comment: @Christian - Not a duplicate. This question is asking about the logical size as well as the physical.

Comment: @Oded - The guy asking the question in the link already provides a method of finding the logical size: var length = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length;

Comment: @Christian - The answer does, the question however, is not the same. You could have linked to the answer as one that answer this question as well.

Comment: @Oded - okay thats true. But all information can be found in the link, including complete code for both methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(new FileInfo(path).Length)
```

is the actual size.
As for size on disk, I don't think there's an API to get it, but you can get it using the actual size, and the cluster size.

There's some info on the calculation required here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/85bf76ac-a254-41d4-a3d7-e7803c8d9bc3

Comment: This isn't always correct... eg some files processed by archiving systems have a size on disk = a single cluster (say 4k), no matter the size reported - See eg Symantex Enterprise Vault