# Determine size of a file by reading its lines

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io

I have an app that reads a huge text file (about more than 100MB) line by line.

As it takes so much time for the app to read the file, I'd like to add a StatusStripProgressBar at its bottom, indicating how much time remains until the end of loading.

I tried to compare the file length to the length of the strings being read, but I don't get the same result. I also tried to convert the string to bytes, but it still differs, for example:

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream) 
{
   s = sr.ReadLine;
   TotalStringSize += s.Length;
   UTF8ToASCII += UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(s);
   UTF8ToBigEndianUnicode += UTF8Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetByteCount(s);
   UTF8ToDefault += UTF8Encoding.Default.GetByteCount(s);
   UTF8ToUnicode += UTF8Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(s);
   UTF8ToUTF32 += UTF8Encoding.UTF32.GetByteCount(s);
   UTF8ToUTF7 += UTF8Encoding.UTF7.GetByteCount(s);
   UTF7ToASCII  = UTF7Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(s);
   //
   // ...
   //
}
```

The results I get are either higher or lower than the result given by `System.IO.FileStream.Length`.
Any idea?

**EDIT: The framework used is .NET 2.0**

Comment: Unicode characters are stored in 2 bytes whereas normal characters are stored in only one byte. It all depends on the type of encoding your file is in

Comment: Isn't it a possibility to use sr.Position compared to the sr.Length to display the progress?

Comment: Is it necessary to show the (already loaded) contents of the file while loading?

Comment: @Me.Name is there such method (sr.Length)? I didn't write it but sr is a streamReader

Comment: @StephaneT No, just the progress of the loading

Comment: Is it an option to use StreamReader.Read(buffer, index, count) in fixed increments that are multiples of 2 and converting the bytes to string as you go?

Comment: @GianT971 So it is, I assumed sr was a FileStream based on the text underneath the code example, but seeing sr uses readline, I could have known it was a streamreader. In that case: sr.BaseStream.Position / sr.BaseStream.Length (available depending on the type of stream used)

Comment: @Me.Name yeah, I just saw that baseStream stuff, but as I use sr.ReadLine, sr.BaseStream.Position does not increase, it sticks to 1024. But that is probably a good clue to achieve my goal

Comment: @StephaneT Not really, as the app has to deal with the information brought by each line, line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sr.ReadLine` strips from the returned string the carriage return/line feed couple of chars.
You need to keep count for these characters missing in the returned string but present in the overall file lenght.

Comment: Nice, I just have to add those 2 characters on each loop and it does the job. Thanks!

Comment: good point. Is it possible that OP also has to compare with FileInfo.Length instead of stream length as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959983/how-to-check-logical-and-physical-file-size-on-disk-using-c-sharp-file-api ?