# Is there a Java equivalent of GetCompressedFileSize?

Tags: java, filesize, sparse-file, on-disk, compressed-files

I am looking to get accurate (i.e. the real size on disk and not the normal size that includes all the 0's) measurements of sparse files in Java.

In C++ on Windows one would use [`GetCompressedFileSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getcompressedfilesizew). I have yet to come across how one would go about doing that in Java?

If there isn't a direct equivalent, how would I go about measuring the data within a sparse file, as opposed to the size including all of the zeros?

For clarification, I am look for this to run the sparse file measurements on both on Linux OS as well as Windows, however I don't mind coding two separate applications!

Comment: i assume your platform is Windows?

Comment: Hi Michael, I have edited my question to answer this. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling Win32 API method from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389156/calling-win32-api-method-from-java)

Comment: I have added an answer for Linux, although i am not sure in it for all 100%

Comment: @Robᵩ I do not think this is a duplicate as the edited question wants a solution for windows and linux, so it can't just call the Win32 function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it on Windows alone, you can write it with Java Native Interface

```
class NativeInterface{
   public static native long GetCompressedFileSize(String filename);
}
```

and in C/C++ file:

```c
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_NativeInterface_GetCompressedFileSize
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring javaString)
{
    const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString, 0);
 
    char buffer[512];
    strcpy(buffer, nativeString);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString, nativeString);
    return (jlong) GetCompressedFileSize(buffer, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure Java solution you can try [jnr-posix](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix/). Here's an [example implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38045730/995714)

```
import jnr.posix.*;

final POSIX p = POSIXFactory.getPOSIX();
final int S_BLKSIZE = 512; // from sys/stat.h
final FileStat stat = p.stat("/path/to/file");
final long bytes = stat.blocks() * S_BLKSIZE;
```

However currently the function [won't work for Windows](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix/issues/120). Until that's fixed you have to use platform-specific code like below

- On Linux use the [`stat64`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat64) system call

  > The st_blocks field indicates the number of blocks allocated to the file, 512-byte units. (This may be smaller than st_size/512 when the file has holes.)

  - You can also run the [`stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) command. The number of allocated blocks can be seen in the `Blocks` field, or printed with the `%b` format specifier
  - Or use [`du` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/du) (without `--apparent-size` option)

    > **--apparent-size**
    >
    > - print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like
- On Windows you can call the [`GetCompressedFileSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getcompressedfilesizea) API

  - Alternatively you can also run `fsutil file layout` with admin rights to get detailed information about a file. Find the `$DATA` stream.

    - If you see *Resident | No clusters allocated* in the flags like this then it's a resident file and size on disk would be 0.

      ```
      PS C:\Users>  fsutil file layout .\desktop.ini

      ********* File 0x000800000003dbde *********
      File reference number   : 0x000800000003dbde
      File attributes         : 0x00000026: Hidden | System | Archive
      File entry flags        : 0x00000000
      Link (ParentID: Name)   : 0x001f0000000238c8: HLINK Name   : \Users\desktop.ini
      ...
      Stream                  : 0x080  ::$DATA
          Attributes          : 0x00000000: *NONE*
          Flags               : 0x0000000c: Resident | No clusters allocated
          Size                : 174
          Allocated Size      : 176
      ```
    - If you don't see the resident flag then check the *Allocated Size* field, it's the file's size on disk

      ```
      PS D:\>  fsutil file layout .\nonresident.txt

      ********* File 0x000400000000084e *********
      File reference number   : 0x000400000000084e
      File attributes         : 0x00000020: Archive
      File entry flags        : 0x00000000
      Link (ParentID: Name)   : 0x0005000000000005: HLINK Name   : \nonresident.txt
      ...
      Stream                  : 0x080  ::$DATA
          Attributes          : 0x00000000: *NONE*
          Flags               : 0x00000000: *NONE*
          Size                : 1,520
          Allocated Size      : 4,096
          Extents             : 1 Extents
                              : 1: VCN: 0 Clusters: 1 LCN: 1,497,204
      ```

For more information you can read the below questions

- [How do I query "Size on disk" file information?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9903679/995714)
- [Get size of file on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3750590/995714)

Answer (score 0):

Since an answer was given for windows. i will try to supply for Linux.

I am not sure, but i think it will do the trick (C++):

```
#include <linux/fs.h>
ioctl(file, BLKGETSIZE64, &file_size_in_bytes);
```

This can be loaded in the same way that was described in the @Aniket answer (JNI)

Comment: This isn't correct. [`GetCompressedFileSize` returns the real size on disk for compressed and sparse files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getcompressedfilesizea)