# How do you get the file on disk, and not just the file size in Java?

Tags: java, filesystems

I need the filesize on disk and not the file size.

```java
File myFile = new File ("C:\\Send\\Capture.png");
System.out.println((int)myFile.length());
```

This code gives the file size. I need the file size on disk. They always happen to be different, like in the picture below, right?

[image]

Comment: In Java there is nothing to do with hadware or Operating System. You can only find the No. of bytes in a File not in terms of disk space.But using JNI from Java you may find.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder no, there is no any philosophic problem to have such thing in a java api

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750590/c-sharp-get-file-size-on-disk)

the answer is provided for c# , but since it uses win32 API functions , you can easily convert it to java. the function used to get the size on disk is [GetCompressedFileSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

hope that helps