# Java how to get file's disk space like Linux's command "du"?

Tags: java, linux

I know Java can use `File.length(), FileChannel.size()` or `RandomAccessFile.length()` to get a file's length, but this equals Linux's command "ls". However, when I create a file with a specific length as follows:

```
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(filePath,"rw");
    randomAccessFile.setLength(10485760);
```

and use "ls -l filePath", I get the file's length is 10485760, but using "du filePath" only gets 0.

So, how to use Java to get the file's real used disk space?

Comment: Look up *sparse file*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per answer  to question pertaining to Windows ,[How do you get the file on disk, and not just the file size in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259549/how-do-you-get-the-file-on-disk-and-not-just-the-file-size-in-java),   there is no  way to do it by one Java command,  you can run Linux `du`  from Java,  have a look here for technics [How to run Linux commands in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403226/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-java).