# How to get exact directory size on disk

Tags: c#, .net, windows, pinvoke, filesize

I'm new in working with the Windows file system and I've been stuck on this problem for a few days. I'm coding with C# and what I want is to get the exact "size on disk" of a directory, like displayed in the Properties dialog of directories on Windows 7.

Now I am able to get a rough figure, traversing through every file and every subdirectory in the directory, using the API `GetCompressedFileSize` in `kernel32.dll` for compressed files and the `FileInfo.Length` property rounded to a multiple of the cluster size for normal files.

I found that some files share clusters (?) (size on disk not a multiple of cluster size) while others occupy clusters separately, then I can't get an exact size on disk, whether to round the size to a multiple of the cluster size or not.

There are also symbolic links which do not occupy disk space, and I can't find a way to distinguish them from normal directories. The size I get is much larger than the exact size as I'm unable to avoid calculating the sizes of those links.

I guess there must be an API or something to get the exact file or directory size on disk. So what is it? Or is there a simpler / faster way to do that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: **not a real answer**

but this may be...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750590/get-size-of-file-on-disk?rq=1

Comment: "Size on disk" is not a well-defined concept, especially on NTFS where a file can contain nonzero data but still occupy zero clusters. Explorer uses a very naïve definition.

Comment: Explorer doesn't even attempt what you ask for

Answer (score 8):

This is a neater way:-

```
private static long GetDirectorySize(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    return dir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(file=> file.Length);
}
```

Basically,  [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a list of `FileInfo`, and we are using its `Length` property to sum the total file size of the directory.

Although it still uses recursion to get directory size, but it sure is a neater way to do so.

To get the Size on disk using C#, you have to dig deeper, like using [GetDiskFreeSpace](http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=getdiskfreespace&namespace=%5bAll%5d)

Also, check out the following [msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85bf76ac-a254-41d4-a3d7-e7803c8d9bc3/how-to-get-the-size-on-disk-of-a-file-in-c?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's neater but it doesn't seem to solve my problem. What I need is "size on disk".

Comment: I have already viewed the two webpages before I posted this question. Compressed files can sometimes share clusters and the formula is hence not suitable, thus I can hardly get the size on disk of directories. Also, I haven't found a way to tell symbolic links from normal files/folders. I'm already using `GetDiskFreeSpace` to find cluster size. All above is what I've thought and tried.