# vb.net get files size on disk of a file from a shared folder

Tags: file, vb.net-2010

Help me please,
Is anyone here knows a solution how to get the file size on disk using vb.net. 
I already tried an answer from
[Get size of file on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750590/get-size-of-file-on-disk).

It's giving me wrong output and it can't read clustersize of mapped shared folder.

My mission is: I need to get the file size on disk of every files from a number of shared folders not local.

Thanks in advanced for your help.

> Got this already in c# but i was looking forward for a solution in vb.net thanks

Comment: The shared file system offers a layer of abstraction above physical storage. I'm not sure that the information is principally available to you.

Comment: Hello @EricJ. . I don't really know what's wrong with vb. but in c# I was able to get the file size on disk accurately just as equal with that shown from file property.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Dim length as Int64 = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length
```

Comment: `FileInfo(path).Length` will give file size not file on disk :)