# Size on Disk value through powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, freebsd, ntfs

I have files on a freebsd server that are shared to my windows machine. I'd like to sort them through powershell by their size on disk value. If I right click them in windows explorer and see their properties, I can see these values being different. I do not want the values in the parenthesis. How do I achieve this? I googled but only found ways to get the different size values, not the size on disk. Here's the example:

[image: example]

Comment: I would probably start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750590/get-size-of-file-on-disk).

Comment: @RyanBemrose I tried that, but the solution only returns the top number, the 922 MB. I need a function that returns "Size on disk"... Also, as I stated before, this is on a network drive formatted as ZFS and offered to me through samba, not a local drive.